# Android Multiuser DIsplay Different Templates

Tags: android

I have a question that I am struggling to find the answer to. What I am looking to do is create an app that will show a different template depending on the user that signs in.

For example, two users A and B. When A logs in I am hoping for them to see a tabbed template that will have features x,y and z but when B logs in I am hoping they will see a simple activity with feature c.

Ideally there will be a point of contact for the admin that will allow them manage the different templates and who sees which ones.

Is this something that can be achieved at all or is it a waste of time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you please tell me exactly how you wanna show templates to the user like in listview or something else.
    Secondly the thing which you want is achievable this has to be done from the server end suppose if you are showing your template in a listview so server will send you data accordingly like if user A logs in the db will give you value of the templates which your admin wants to show to your user and later you can open the templates according to the listview item selected .
   Happy Coding .

Comment: Does that not turn it into a web app then? How would you go about storing the templates on a server?